# Turning off automatic tag closing in emacs web mode?

Tags: emacs

When working with HTML templates in web mode I'm frustrated by the automatic closing of tags. When inside a `<div>` I type `</` before it fills it in with `div>`.

This make copy/pasting from another place into my terminal annoying.

How do I turn off the feature?

Comment: Emacs-24.4 will solve this problem by using the special paste support of terminals.  IOW the terminal will tell Emacs that "this is a paste" so that Emacs can then insert the text as-is rather than behaving as if it were typed by the user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is controlled by the `web-mode-tag-auto-close-style` variable:

```
Tag auto-close style:
0=no auto-closing
1=auto-close with </
2=auto-close with > and </.
```

The default value is `1`. Disable automatic tag closing completely with

```lisp
(eval-after-load "web-mode"
  '(setq web-mode-tag-auto-close-style 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

To enable this feature:

`(setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing t)`

And to disable it:

`(setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing nil)`

Ref: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/358